# Exception in thread "Thread-21" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FAIL_ON_SYMBOL_HASH_OVERFLOW

Tags: elasticsearch, jackson, elastic-stack

I wrote java code which connect to ElasticSearch node and save documents in index. I got below error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-21" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
> FAIL_ON_SYMBOL_HASH_OVERFLOW

I use these versions according to below link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-notes-7.7.0.html

**Upgrade to Jackson 2.10.3 #53523 (issues: #27032, #45225)**

**Update jackson-databind to 2.8.11.6 #53522 (issue: #45225)**

Could anyone help me?

list of libs:

```
algorithmanimator.jar
annogen-0.1.0.jar
ant-1.7.0.jar
antlr-3.3.jar
antlr-runtime-3.3.jar
appache-commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
appache-commons-lang.jar
appache-commons-logging-1.2.jar
ArchiveLoggerLib.jar
axiom-api-1.2.7.jar
axiom-dom-1.2.7.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar
axis2-1.4.jar
backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
basex-api.jar
bsh-2.0b4.jar
bson-3.0.4.jar
cloning-1.8.5.jar
commandline.jar
commonplugin.jar
commons-codec-1.11.jar
commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-net-3.1.jar
commons-validator-1.5.1.jar
compiler-0.9.6.jar
connector.jar
DJNativeSwing.jar
drools-clips-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-compiler-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-decisiontables-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-jsr94-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-persistence-jpa-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-templates-5.4.0.Final.jar
drools-verifier-5.4.0.Final.jar
ecj-3.5.1.jar
elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-cli-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-core-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-geo-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-rest-client-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-secure-sm-7.7.1.jar
elasticsearch-x-content-7.7.1.jar
geo2Ip.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
graphgenerator.jar
graph.jar
graphTea.jar
graphtea-library.jar
graphtea-main.jar
graphTea-Old.jar
graphtea-ui-library.jar
HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar
hppc-0.8.1.jar
httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar
httpclient-4.5.11.jar
httpclient-cache-4.5.jar
httpclient-win-4.5.jar
httpcore-4.4.13.jar
httpcore-nio-4.4.10.jar
httpmime-4.5.jar
icu4j-60_2.jar
jackson-core-2.8.11.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.11.jar
jackson-dataformat-smile-2.8.11.jar
jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.11.jar
jade4j-0.3.9.jar
Jama-1.0.1.jar
javabuilder.jar
javaee.jar
java-mail-1.4.4.jar
jibx-bind-1.1.5.jar
jibx-run-1.1.5.jar
jna-4.5.1.jar
joda-time-2.10.3.jar
jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar
json-20090211.jar
json-org.jar
json-simple.jar
knowledge-api-5.4.0.Final.jar
knowledge-internal-api-5.4.0.Final.jar
KnowledgeWebServices.jar
lang-mustache-7.5.0.jar
ldapbp-1.0.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
log4j-api-2.13.1.jar
log4j-core-2.13.1.jar
lucene-analyzers-common-8.5.2.jar
lucene-backward-codecs-8.3.0.jar
lucene-core-8.5.2.jar
lucene-grouping-8.5.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-8.5.2.jar
lucene-join-8.5.2.jar
lucene-memory-8.5.2.jar
lucene-misc-8.5.2.jar
lucene-queries-8.5.2.jar
lucene-queryparser-8.5.2.jar
lucene-sandbox-8.5.2.jar
lucene-spatial3d-8.5.2.jar
lucene-spatial-8.4.1.jar
lucene-spatial-extras-8.5.2.jar
lucene-suggest-8.5.2.jar
mongodb-driver-3.0.4.jar
mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar
mvel2-2.1.0.drools16.jar
neethi-2.0.4.jar
objenesis-1.2.jar
org.nmap4j-1.1.0-sources.jar
PersianCalender.jar
poi-3.17.jar
poi-contrib-3.2-final.jar
poi-examples-3.17.jar
poi-excelant-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar
Proc.jar
rank-eval-client-7.5.0.jar
reports.jar
SitraManagementKnowledgeBase.aar
SitraSharedJavaLibs.jar
snakeyaml-1.17.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
sun-jndi-ldap.jar
syslog4j-0.9.46-bin.jar
t-digest-3.2.jar
visualization.jar
woden-api-1.0M8.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
```

Comment: Give us more information like what kind of dependency management system u r using, show us the dependency tree.

Comment: I added list of dependencies in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem, geo2Ip.jar was old and there was old jackson-core library in it, and there was conflict between jackson-core-2.8.11.jar and jackson-core in geo2Ip.jar.

Answer (score 0):

There are conflict libraries.

You said in your question that you are using `jackson-core-2.10.3.jar`

And in your dependency list, I see `jackson-core-2.10.3.jar`

Two different versions causing the conflict. It could probably be transitive dependency. Exclude the one you don't need.

You can refer another [similar forum topic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-nosuchfielderror/58923/8)

Comment: There are real libraries in dependency list. I correct my question

Comment: What is your dependency management system? `maven`?

Comment: actually I put all the dependencies in a folder and run my jar file with this command:  java -cp <jar_file_name>.jar:<dependency_folder> <main_file>

Comment: I would suggest you to use `dependency management system` like `maven` to exclude these conflict dependencies? That's the purpose of these tools.

Comment: I used maven, it does not find any conflicts, but I have the same problem

Comment: Did you check in dependency tree of maven

Comment: yeah, but it does not report any conflict between dependencies!